# Printing an array without stating which one leads leads to a String of random code

Tags: java, arrays

While I was working on a project of mine, I tried to print out an integer from an array using the following code:

```
Random dice = new Random();
int wolfhealth[] = new int[]{dice.nextInt(15)+9};
System.out.println(wolfhealth);
```

I accidentally forgot to state which integer I wanted to print out from the array of integers which lead to it printing out this line of code:

```
[I@75b84c92
```

I have already fixed the issue by changing the 3rd line into

```
System.out.println(wolfhealth[0]);
```

My question is, what does this line of code - `[I@75b84c92` mean exactly? Is it some kind of unique identifier or ID for the array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is output from the default `toString()` implementation from `Object`, as "overridden" for array objects.

The output encodes the type and memory address:

```
[ I @75b84c92
▲ ▲  ▲
│ │  └─── hash code
│ └─── of integer
└─── array
```

Comment: Last hex string is not memory address.  It is a hash code.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in java are referent types. That means that you actually store a reference(an address) in stack memory to some other memory in heap. The first 2 symbols mean that this is an array of ints ([I) and latter mean that it located in some address in heap space (@ 75b84c92). Hope this helps to understand it. You may also see a contents of an array (mainly for debug purposes) using `Arrays.toString(a)`

Answer (score 2):

Taking an array arr for example all three will print the same result

```
    int[] arr  = new int[20];

    System.out.println(arr);
    System.out.println(arr.toString());
    System.out.println(String.format("%s@%x", arr.getClass(), arr.hashCode()));
```

Essentially when System.out.println is called every object's toStriing method is called so the effect of calling arr.toString also yields the same thing as what printing arr gives. The last statement is just demonstrating what's being done inside toString of the array class.